# BUILD FAILED in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

compile:

> BUILD FAILED
>        D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following
>         error occurred while executing this line:
>        D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
>         error occurred while executing this line:
>        D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to fin
>         d a javac compiler;
>         com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>           Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>         It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
>
> path is ::C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
>          C:\Windows\System32\Wind
>           owsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;
>             D:\Progr
>            am Files\nodejs\;E:\practicum\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;
>            E:\practicum\Softwa
>            res\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\pl
>            atform-tools;
>              E:\practicum\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundl
>            e-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools
>             ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\lib;C:\Pro
>            gram Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;
>            C:\Users\srinivas\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Please tell me how to refix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make "JAVA_HOME " variable point to a JDK installation, not JRE.
You are referencing the runtime environment, not the development kit - it can't find the compiler because its not there.

It should be something like this:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"

However the path and the JDK version may vary on your system.

Answer (score -1):

As it says

```
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

Your **JAVA_HOME** is set to **JRE** it should be set to **JDK**

set your **JAVA_HOME** to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;
```

or to the version of jdk is available